# Less CSS responsive modifier

Tags: less

I'm trying to create a utility-first collection of CSS classes, similar to Tailwind but in Less. A big part of this is using responsive modifiers, using this className syntax: `.large\:text-white`.

The code below works great, except for one thing: the `\:` shouldn't be rendered on the default classes (the classes outside of the media queries. They should render using a period, as expected `.foo`.

I can't figure out how to solve this.

```
@screens: {
    small:          320px;
    medium:         768px;
    large:          1024px;
}

@padding: {
    0:              0;
    10:             1rem;
    20:             20rem;
    30:             30rem;
}

@colors: {
    white:          #fff;
    silver:         hsla(0, 0%, 90%, 1);
}

@responsive-modifiers: true;

#config () {
    .generate(pt, padding, @padding);
    .generate(py, padding-top, @padding);
    .generate(text, color, @colors);
    .generate(background, background-color, @colors);
}

// Call the mixin
#config();


each(@screens, {
    @media (min-width : @value) {
        .@{key} when (@responsive-modifiers = true) {
            #config();
        }
    }
})

.generate(@prefix, @property, @list) {
    each(@list, {
        &\:@{prefix}-@{key} {
            @{property}: @value;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding a period/dot variable. Here's the final code. Works well:

```
@screens: {
    small:          320px;
    medium:         768px;
    large:          1024px;
}

@padding: {
    0:              0;
    10:             1rem;
    20:             20rem;
    30:             30rem;
}

@colors: {
    white:          #fff;
    silver:         hsla(0, 0%, 90%, 1);
}

@responsive-modifiers: true;

#config () {
    .generate(pt, padding, @padding);
    .generate(py, padding-top, @padding);
    .generate(text, color, @colors);
    .generate(background, background-color, @colors);
}

@period: .;
@{period} {
    #config();
}


each(@screens, {
    @media (min-width : @value) {
        .@{key}&\: when (@responsive-modifiers = true) {
            #config();
        }
    }
})

.generate(@prefix, @property, @list) {
    each(@list, {
        &@{prefix}-@{key} {
            @{property}: @value;
        }
    });
}
```